# Reading Attributes from XML

Tags: c#, xml

What I'm trying to do is read some data from an xml file and assign the data to a label when the user clicks on an item in a listbox. This is the code I have tried, the code compiles but nothing happens to my label.

```
private void lbAllModules_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextReader inforeader = new XmlTextReader(workingDir + @"\modules.xml");


        while (inforeader.Read())
        {
            if ((inforeader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (inforeader.Name == "modulecode"))
            {

                if (inforeader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    lblCodeOut.Text = inforeader.GetAttribute(0);
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the cumbersome `XmlReader` API instead of `XmlDocument` or even better `XDocument`?

Comment: XMLReader is how I've been taught to do this and i would need to stick to using this method

Comment: You should give a try to LINQ to XML...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"C:\modules.xml");

 // Query the data for first attribute of element 'modecode'
var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("modulecode")
        where c.HasAttributes
        select (string)c.Attributes().FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var item in q)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your node is called exactly "modulecode". Comparison is case-sensitive. You can use

```
string.Compare(inforeader.Name,"modulecode", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
```

for case-insensitive comparison. Then try

```
if(inforeader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
   lblCodeOut.Text = inforeader.Value;
```